# is there a way to create a new gomock controller without NewController?

Tags: go, gomock

as title said, is there a way to create a new gomock controller without NewController?
the comment in the package said

```
// NewController returns a new Controller. It is the preferred way to create a
// Controller.
```

I'm wondering if there is a way for creating it without the constructor?

I tried many ways, like creating it using `new()` and assigning the variables directly but the controller won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `Controller` has a private field `expectedCalls` which cannot be set outside the constructor. You need to use `NewController` or `WithContext` functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I saw `WithContext` also calls `NewController`, so in the end to properly create it we need to use the constructor